# Trying to sort an Array based on another Array alphabetical order

Tags: java

I've got 2 ArryLists: an Integers one and a Strings one.

```
ArrayList<String> stars = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> index = new ArrayList<>();

index.add(1);
index.add(2); 
index.add(3); 
index.add(4); 
index.add(5); 
index.add(6);

stars.add("g");
stars.add("c"); 
stars.add("a"); 
stars.add("l"); 
stars.add("b"); 
stars.add("q");
```

I need to rearrange the values of the index ArryList such that stars.get(index.get(i)) will give the stars Array in Alphbetical order

I worte this code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < stars.size(); x++) {
    for (int y = x+1; y < stars.size(); y++) {
        if (stars.get(x).compareTo(stars.get(y)) > 0 ) {
             int temp = index.get(x);
             index.set(x, index.get(y));
             index.set(y, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

but I keep getting this output:

```
[4 2 0 1 3 5]
```

for the index Array

instead of:

```
[2 4 1 0 3 5]
```

can anyone help find what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your're just swapping the elements at position x and y of the index list, you must also swap the values in the star list

```
for (int x = 0; x < stars.size(); x++) {
    for (int y = x + 1; y < stars.size(); y++) {
        if (stars.get(x).compareTo(stars.get(y)) >= 0 ) {
            int temp = index.get(x);
            index.set(x, index.get(y));
            index.set(y, temp);

            String strTmp = stars.get(x);
            stars.set(x, stars.get(y));
            stars.set(y, strTmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: If you can't change the star list then you can use this code

```
for (int x = 0; x < stars.size(); x++) {
    for (int y = x + 1; y < stars.size(); y++) {
        if (stars.get(index.get(x) - 1).compareTo(stars.get(index.get(y) - 1)) >= 0 ) {
            int temp = index.get(x);
            index.set(x, index.get(y));
            index.set(y, temp);
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < index.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(stars.get(index.get(i) - 1) + " ");
}
```

This gives the result

```
a b c g l q
```

Comment: yes, I understand but I'm not alloed to change an stars List.

Comment: It appears you're just trying to have the stars list sorted alphabetically. Use Collections.sort(stars); to sort the stars, also sort the index list too (Assuming its not a sorted list). Then get the stars by stars.get(index.get(i));

Comment: @Shlomi Shabtai: Collections.sort(stars) changes stars. Is that acceptable?

Comment: I'm afriad not.
I have to keep stars in its original order

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting the indexes, but not using them to fetch the values to compare. Change your code to use the index values to get the stars value:

```
for (int x = 0; x < stars.size(); x++) {
    for (int y = x+1; y < stars.size(); y++) {
        if (stars.get(index.get(x)-1).compareTo(stars.get(index.get(y)-1)) > 0 ) {
            int temp = index.get(x);
            index.set(x, index.get(y));
            index.set(y, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the -1 is done because you are populating your index array from 1 through 6 instead of 0 through 5. This gives the result [3 5 2 1 4 6]. If your expected answer is [2 4 1 0 3 5], remove the -1 from the fetches and populate your index array with 0 through 5:

```
index.add(0);
index.add(1);
index.add(2);
index.add(3);
index.add(4);
index.add(5);

for (int x = 0; x < stars.size(); x++) {
    for (int y = x+1; y < stars.size(); y++) {
        if (stars.get(index.get(x)).compareTo(stars.get(index.get(y)) > 0 ) {
            int temp = index.get(x);
            index.set(x, index.get(y));
            index.set(y, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don`t really know what should you do, to get this:

> [2 4 1 0 3 5]

But if you put these values in sorted map:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
    map.put("g", 1);
    map.put("c", 2);
    map.put("a", 3);
    map.put("l", 4);
    map.put("b", 5);
    map.put("q", 6);
    System.out.println(map.values());
```

you`ll get this result:

> [3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6]

Comment: just use the index value `0...5` instead of `1...6`.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the `stars` list, then you can do this:

```
Collection<Integer> values = new TreeMap<String, Integer>() {{
  stars.forEach(key -> put(key, size()));
}}.values();
```

What's happening here?

1. Create an anonymous `TreeMap`, which is a sorted map by order of the keys.
2. The two `{{ }}` are an anonymous initializer of the map.
3. For each entry of `stars`, add the key with the appropriate index (`size()` is getting incremented with each `put()`, starting with `0`).
4. Get the values.

Results:

```
[2, 4, 1, 0, 3, 5]
```

---

But assuming, you need to keep the `index` list, too, and you want to implement the sorting yourself, then you need to swap the `stars` *and* `index`:

```
for (int x = 0; x < stars.size(); x++) {
  for (int y = x + 1; y < stars.size(); y++) {
    if (stars.get(x).compareTo(stars.get(y)) > 0) {
      Collections.swap(stars, x, y);
      Collections.swap(index, x, y);
    }
  }
}
```

Which will result in:

```
[3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6]
```

It seems like you want to have a 0-based index, instead (but seriously: why initialize the index list with a `1`?), then you need to subtract `1` of each index value:

```
System.out.println(index.stream().map(i -> i - 1).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```